# How to turn off/on Angular Table(ng-table) grouping?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

just like the title said, I want to turn the groupping on/off with some button or javascript command/API.

How to do this with `ng-table`(http://ng-table.com/#/) ? I know there is some table plugin out there that can do this, like https://ag-grid.com/example.php

Comment: [From the docs](http://ng-table.com/#/grouping/demo-enabling). Is that what you need?

Comment: Nope, I want to turn it on ( show the grouping ) and off ( remove the grouping and make it ordinary table )

Comment: Unfortunately you would have to build up a conditional layout for that matter, as the variables to access change entirely throughout enabling/disabling the grouping functionality. Are you using any other frameworks beside AngularJS (interested in your backend here)?